# How to access an array from ouside a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I am using an array to store values pulled from a database, but I wonder how I can then access them from outside the while loop?

```
$lecturers_temp = array(array());
$i = 0;

$q2 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availability`";

$result2 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q2);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $lecturers = $row2['uninum']; 
    $lecturers_temp = array(array());
    $lecturers_temp[$i][0] = $row2['uninum'];

    echo $lecturers_temp [$i] [0] . "<BR><BR>";
    $i++;

}

//when I try this I get an undefined offset error
echo $lecturers_temp [1] [0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because you reset the array in your while loop. Get rid of `$lecturers_temp = array(array());` in your while loop and see if that gets the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `$lecturers_temp = array(array());` code from `while` block. Also to simplicity data you can use one dimension array:

```
$lecturers_temp = array();

$i = 0;

$q2 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availability`";

$result2 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q2);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $lecturers_temp[$i] = $row2['uninum'];

    echo $lecturers_temp[$i] . "<BR><BR>";
    $i++;
}

//when I try this I get an undefined offset error
echo $lecturers_temp [1];
```

Comment: Thanks Valery, I have it in a 2D array, because I plan to use the other dimension to store other data I want to pull from the database....thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

The `$lecturers_temp = array(array());` in the while loop gets rid of all the previous items stored in the array.